# Reliable online port scanner to check my DSL router?

Tags: networking, security, ports

can you suggest me a reliable online port scanner to check (open/closed) the ports of my DSL-router ?
Thanks !

Comment: Hello Mimetic, Welcome to super user! Asking for recommendations for software is offtopic on super user, you may be better off asking on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is it you're trying to determine is open/closed?  Are you trying to configure an open port for a service/game?  Afraid of a vulnerability?  Also, have you tried checking your DSL modem and/or router's configuration page, to see what it has listed as opened and closed?

Comment: Hi and sorry for being off-topic. Thanks for the other stack suggestion. @ServiceManager I have configured my DSL router but it seems quite limited and has some kind of ISP-set stuff that prevents further configuration it seems. I'm also not that savvy in networking. Therefore I wanted to at least be able to scan my connection with a third-party, online, reliable source to see if anything worrisome was open. Basically I want to have everything closed for a secure normal home use. No web server or any other SSH or Telnet feature needed.

Comment: @MimeticPolyAlloy Ok, so you want all service ports closed to increase security, but are unable to further configure the modem/router due to ISP lock down.  Have you tried calling them to have them remotely configure it for this security?

Comment: @ServiceManager indeed I would like all service ports closed but still be able to browse the internet and play occasional games on steam basically. Basically for some reason it's impossible to find a comprehensive list of the ports closed or open on my router. That's why I wanted to scan from a reliable web based port scanner to make sure nothing is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to run `nmap` from a different location (Internet connection). A friend's computer, a rented VPS or even your smartphone over 3G would be enough. Syntax is simply `nmap <ip>` to scan 1000 common ports, where ip is the external ip address of your home DSL connection. On Android I would install Termux and then:

1. `apt update`
2. `apt install nmap`
3. `nmap <ip>`

I cannot recommend a specific app for iOS for not having tested any, although I believe there are that offer the same functionality.

To answer the question more directly (online port scan tools): there is [MXtoolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/PortScan.aspx) which among other services offers a limited port scan, and [T1shopper](http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan) which has a more customizable port scan tool; both are reliable and tested.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes please ! Could it be run from my iPhone via 3G for example ? Do you mean another location on the home network or outside ? I guess outside but not sure. Thanks !

Comment: Actually it's not first 1000 ports, but 1000 most common ports for each protocol based on popularity values in the [nmap-services](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/nmap-services) file.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys ! However IOSmap seems like something that either has to be installed on a router (so a different "IOS") or on a jailbroken iPhone seeing how it has to be installed. http://www.ciscozine.com/nmap-for-ios-no-iosmap/

Comment: @MimeticPolyAlloy, That is the Cisco IOS which runs on their routers, not the Apple iOS (note different capitalisation).

Comment: @MimeticPolyAlloy. Also, for checking a single port you can use canyouseeme.org.

Comment: @Darren Indeed I was thinking the same for the Cisco IOS tool. Thanks for canyouseeme.org. I tried it on port 80 and got _I could not see your service on <IP> on port (80) Reason: Connection timed out_, if the connection timed out does it mean that it's closed ?

Comment: @MimeticPolyAlloy yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a few mistakes in my answer! Of course nmap does not scan by default ports 1-1000, and IOSMap is completely off topic. There appear to be a few apps on the App Store but I shouldn't venture into talking about software I haven't used.